# How and where are GPUs used in scientific simulations?

Tags: gpgpu, scientific-computing

How and where are [GPUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU) used in scientific simulations (esp. in astrophysics/cosmology)?

Comment: @Kev: Given that I agreed with David (both mods on Physics.SE), would you care to comment on what we *should* have done with this? Would moving to Programmers have been better?

Comment: @dmckee - The problem is that it's open-ended and will result in a list/poll/extended discussion....which as we know are off limits. But if you think this is wrong then post a question on [Meta] for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Take a look at [NVIDIA CUDA showcase](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_showcase_stage.html). First two applications mentioned are astronomy/astrophysics.
2. [Astrophysics tag on GPGPU.org](http://gpgpu.org/tag/astrophysics)

Answer (score 2):

It's quite a new field, but I've seen an application in astrophysics once.

Generally GPUs can be used for parallelizable calculations (per pixel or per event), with simple C-compatible (not object oriented) routines, e.g. fourier trafo, histograms, etc

Comment: "I've seen an application in astrophysics once" - what was it?

Comment: [this one](http://www.physik.rwth-aachen.de/fileadmin/user_upload/www_physik/Institute/Inst_3B/Forschung/IceCube/publications/bachelor_thesis_RR.pdf) - cosmic ray moon shadow seen by IceCube - the application of GPUs is rather down to earth, likelihood calculation

Answer (score -1):

The simulation in Physics usually needs to consider thousands/millions of particles in cosmology and astrophysics, in Electromagnetic (e.g. in the light propagation g-search "+fdtd +gpu") and fluid simulations, in biological contexts, atmosphere, etc.  The GPU can harness the parallelism that is present in the universe.  The hardware and the software are ready (g-search Open-CL, CUDA). You can have a supercomputer in your desk.  In almost all simulations we can use parallel reasoning: define how to model the response of one component and apply to all components propagating the interactions in time steps.

[see my PSE-answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8517/two-orbiting-planets-in-perpendicular-planes/8685#8685) to see a nice picture where my GPU(300 processors) was used to simulate gravitacional interactions using *direct* N-Body code.